# Concurrent reads/writes from/on Redis Set - single server multiple clients

Tags: c#, redis, stackexchange.redis

We have some applications running on different PC's. There must be a Redis server holds a shared key/value's queue for all applications. Each application has 2 threads, a thread for filling queue and another for iterating and processing queue.

Suppose the queue contains these items: [(1,value1),(2,v2),(3,v3),(4,v4)]. What we want is that item with key 3 to be peeked by just one client and a concurrent request peek item with key 4 or any other key.

- What is the best way to implement this with Redis?
- Is there any way to reach the goal via string `SET`?
- Is a pub/sub system can be implemented for this with Redis?

Thanks in advance.

**NOTE** The clients written in C#, [StackExchange.Redis](https://github.com/StackExchange/StackExchange.Redis)

Answer (score 1):

To make processes mutually exclusive you can use [`RedLock.Net`](https://github.com/samcook/RedLock.net). It is a [`Distributed Lock Manager`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Distributed_lock_manager) which is like a `lock` statement that works for processes which don't have a way to know each other. Here's is an example:

```
public async Task ProcessMessage(Message message) 
{   
    // the thing we are trying to lock, i.e: "3"
    var resource = message.Key; 

    // determines how long will the lock be alive untill it's automatically released
    var expiry = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(30);

    // how long will the thread wait trying to acquire the lock
    var wait = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10);

    // time span between each request to Redis trying to acquire the lock
    var retry = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1);

    // blocks the thread until acquired or 'wait' timeout
    using (var redLock = await redlockFactory.CreateLockAsync(resource, expiry, wait, retry))
    {
        // make sure we got the lock
        if (redLock.IsAcquired)
        {
            // we successfully locked the resource, now other processes will have to wait
            ProcessMessageInternal(message.Value);
        }
        else 
        {
            // could't get the lock within the wait time
            // handle collision
        }
    }

    // the lock is automatically released at the end of the using block
    // which means the IDisposable.Dispose method makes a request to Redis to release the lock
}
```

Notice how I'm using the message's `Key` as the resource to lock on to. This means that any other process will not be able to lock onto the resource until the lock is either disposed or expired.

As for implementing the pub/sub system I highly recommend that you an [`Azure Storage Queue`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/queues/storage-dotnet-how-to-use-queues), create a [`Queue Trigger`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-create-storage-queue-triggered-function) and subscribe your program to it.

All this sounds complicated but it's very easy to implement: you can separate your application' threads into two processes:

**Message reader:** who simply en-queues a message whenever a message arrives like this:

```
// Retrieve storage account from connection string.
CloudStorageAccount storageAccount = CloudStorageAccount.Parse(
    CloudConfigurationManager.GetSetting("StorageConnectionString"));

// Create the queue client.
CloudQueueClient queueClient = storageAccount.CreateCloudQueueClient();

// Retrieve a reference to a queue.
CloudQueue queue = queueClient.GetQueueReference("myqueue");

// Create the queue if it doesn't already exist.
queue.CreateIfNotExists();

var message = // get message

var json = SerializeMessage(message);

// Create a message and add it to the queue.
CloudQueueMessage message = new CloudQueueMessage(json);
queue.AddMessage(message);
```

**Message processor:** who will subscribe to the queue by using by making use of the `QueueTrigger`, there is a project template for Visual Studio that's called `Azure Functions` that you simply need to pass on the storage connection string along with the queue name and it will handle the concurrency for you. This process will escalate horizontally (meaning that there will be many instances of it) so it needs to be mutually exclusive with its sibling and will achieve that by using `RedLock.Net`. The azure function will lock like this:

```
public class Functions 
{
    public static void ProcessQueueMessage([QueueTrigger(QueueName)] string serializedMessage)
    {
        var message = DeserializeMessage(serializedMessage);

        MessageProcesor.ProcessMessage(message);
    }
}
```

You can also use a [`Service Bus Queue`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-bus-messaging/service-bus-dotnet-get-started-with-queues) instead of the `Azure Storage Queue` if you need to process bigger messages at a high rate of speed, here's a comparison between the two: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-bus-messaging/service-bus-azure-and-service-bus-queues-compared-contrasted

Answer (score 0):

You can use a `LIST` to save these items, and take the `LIST` as a queue. Use [push/pop commands](https://redis.io/commands/blpop) to fill in the queue and fetch items from the queue.

`LIST` guarantees concurrent read/write, and an item is only be fetched by one client.